# Maybe mysql_insert_id() will return unexpected id

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe my question is silly but there's one thing I wish to know about `mysql_insert_id()`. On php.net is written following:

> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

What will be output of this this function if before script reaches line where `mysql_insert_id()` is used another script inserts something in database?

As far as it's known to me it will return id of the last inserted item (does not matter from where). If I am right, I wish to know how to avoid this problem but using `mysql_insert_id()` immediately when insert query is executed (because there still is a little chance to get in "trouble").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will return the id of the last row that was inserted in the current session, so you have nothing to fear. In fact you pass the link identifyer as argument or otherwise it defaults to the last link opened. From the docs

> The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the
>   last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is
>   found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with
>   no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING
>   level error is generated.

So if you have

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

This will always be correct (if mytable has an AUTO_INCREMENT column, of course) because it retrieves the last generated id in the session. If at the same time another user runs exactly the same query, he would have a different session and he would get his id correctly

Comment: +1.  MySQL is a multiuser database; they anticipated issues like this in advance. :)